# what kind/sort of music do

Tags: collocations

All the dictionaries I have checked give *what sort of music* ... and none mentioned *what kind of music*. That was under the head word *music*.

On the other hand, COCA (118 and 10 hits for kind and sort respectively) and Google ngrams give by far more hits for *[what kind](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20kind%20of%20music%2Cwhat%20sort%20of%20music&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20sort%20of%20music%3B%2Cc0) of music [[do]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20kind%20of%20music%20do%2Cwhat%20sort%20of%20music%20do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20kind%20of%20music%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20sort%20of%20music%20do%3B%2Cc0)* than for *what sort of music [do]*.

This is an example for the pattern in one of the dictionaries:

> What sort of music do you listen to?

Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary

How do you explain the observation?

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Do your dictionaries provide useful definitions of the English nouns _kind_ and _sort?_ Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us what is it about those definitions that confuses you.

Comment: @P.E.Dant The OP isn't asking about what _kind_ and _sort_ mean. The question, as framed by a native speaker, is: Why is "what kind of music" so much more common than "what sort of music"—contrary to what's suggested by dictionaries' use of "what sort of music" as an example and their avoidance of "what kind of music"?

Comment: My intention (again based upon prior acquaintance with the OP) was to clarify that the meanings of _kind_ and _sort_ are clearly understood. I hope _you_ can explain why _kind of music_ is more common than _sort of music!_

Comment: It's impossible to explain definitively why the phrase _kind of music_ takes precedence over the phrase _sort of music_ in the samples used by the Corpus of Contemporary American English at Brigham Young University in the USA. There are so many possible explanations for the phenomenon that a doctoral thesis could conceivably be presented on the subject. It may be that since the corpus is limited in its source to published material, the preponderance of music-related digitally accessible texts favors the N. American language group, where _kind_ is more commonly used in this context than _sort._

Comment: Dictionaries especially in recent years claim that they reflect the language being used, and to support their claim they use corpora. Now when I checked a few of the high-profile dictionaries for the case of (What kind of music do ... vs What sort of music do ..) I found that Google Ngrams and COCA "prove" that the question "What kind of music do .." is by far more common that "What sort of music do ..." even though the dictionaries give only "What sort of music do ...". Conclusion is the search proves the contrary. Cont...

Comment: I did not mean to ask for a justification of why one pattern is more than the other. Let me restate my question. How do you explain the observation that the corpora above do not reflect the language in the dictionaries. In fact, it should be the other way around, the dictionaries do not reflect the language in the corpora.

Comment: The dictionaries do not say that "What kind of music do ..." is not used. Dictionaries give examples that reflect common usage. I did not see that in this case. By the way, these are the dictionaries that give examples for "What sort of music do ..." Oxford Essential Dictionary
, Oxford Learner's Wordfinder Dictionary
, and Cambridge Advanced Learners Dictionary. All the dictionaries even the American ones I checked never mentioned any patterns having "kind of music" in the examples or definitions.

Comment: The Longman Collocations Dictionary and Thesaurusa, however, mentions kind of music in this line "kind/type/sort of music *I don’t listen to that kind of music at home.*". This is good but my question still stands.

Comment: This is not restricted to COCA but also Google Ngram. I did not check BNC. I'm not sure if there's free access to the corpus. I did not intend to carry out research to find out the answer to this question. I am not an expert or a specialist-just an ELL learner.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother much! They both mean the same thing. It is **just a style!**

Straight from the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/speaking/kind-of-and-sort-of):

> *Kind of and sort of are very common expressions in speaking. They soften other words and phrases so that they do not appear too direct or exact. **Kind of is more common in American English. Sort of is more common in British English.***